Cannot use CKAN API for my Localhost installation
I've installed a CKAN in my laptop and I can access it via browser with the localhost address, but I cannot access via API.
Is there some configuration I didn't do?
If I make a Google App Script API call to some CKAN repository, I get the expected response.
function conectarComCKAN() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://dados.ufrj.br/api/3/action/group_list');
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());  
}

Response:
11:11:13    Notificação Execução iniciada
11:11:13    Informação  {"help": "https://dados.ufrj.br/api/3/action/help_show?name=group_list", "success": true, "result": ["chs", "pr5", "pr6", "pr1", "pr4", "pr3", "pr7", "pr2", "siarq", "sibi"]}
11:11:14    Notificação Execução concluída

If I make the same API call to my localhost repository, I get an error.
function conectarComCKAN() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://localhost/api/3/action/group_list');
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());  
}

Error:
11:16:40    Notificação Execução iniciada
11:16:41    Erro    
Exception: DNS error: https://localhost/api/3/action/group_list
conectarComCKAN @ Código.gs:2


Use the HTTP method, not HTTPS.
If your CKAN instance is running on port 5000, use "http://localhost:5000/...".
